# Insult Generator Gone Wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making an insult generator for class that uses one word from three lists within a tuple named `allWords`. For some reason, while my `generateInsult()` function generates an insult, my `generateInsults()` function generates `"Thou A l l!"`

Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Here's the relevant code

```
def generateInsult(word='allWords'):
    insult = "Thou " + random.choice(word[0]) + " " + random.choice(word[1]) + " " + random.choice(word[2]) + "!"
    return insult

def generateInsults(word='allWords'):
    insults = list()
    for i in range(100):
        insults.append(generateInsult('AllWords'))
    return insults
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have a 3-tuple of lists called `allWords`. You should remove the quotes around the default argument, ie change the following lines:

```
def generateInsult(word=allWords):
    ...

def generateInsults(word=allWords):
    ...
    insults.append(generateInsult(word))
```

Comment: That was it Selcuk - I can't tell you how much you have brightened my day, it was a silly mistake but I've been up all night trying to figure it out. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You take a random choice out of a single character.

The character with index zero, the character with index 1 and the character with index 2.